# Unable to create MultiUserChat with Smack: receiving SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply

Tags: android, exception, smack

While Creating group I'm getting an Exception: 
"SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply"

This is the group create method with a reply time setted on 50sec.
I am able to do login, one to one chat. 
But while trying to create a group getting the below exception on muc.create(nick);

```
public void createGroup() {

    String roomId = "Group_test003" + "@iscoveri.com";
    String nick = "Grouptest";

    try {

 manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(xmppCON);

        MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomId);

        muc.create(nick);

        Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();

        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

        List<FormField> fields = form.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.get(i);
            if (!FormField.Type.hidden.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {

                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }

        List owners = new ArrayList();
        owners.add("8017037677" + "@iscoveri.com");
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);

        muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

MultiUserChat it's not created until an user join it.

So after sendConfiguration you need to join the muc:

```
muc.join("8017037677@iscoveri.com");
```

Edit: by the way, be sure to have a valid service subdomain registered into your server.

Comment: That won't even be possible if `muc.create(nick);` timeouts first.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK set an higher timeout, default it's 3sec, you can try with 15